# Communicate with a specific browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I've created a website in JSP with Servlets.

Users can login and they all get a session attribute with their `userid`.

I created a page with a textbox and button where I can fill in an `userid`.

Upon clicking the button I want to open a popup (url) on the `browser` of the specific user with the `session userid` equals to the `userid` filled in the textbox. The popup should appear immediately an not require a page request to get shown.

What kind of things I should use for this?

I googled, but couldn't find anything usefull.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to show the popup on the next page request or do you want it to be shown immediately?

Comment: @Philipp Immediately, it's a chat popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a chat client can be quite tricky because you have to send data from the server to the client when a message is sent by another user. WebSockets allows you to do this but it is a pretty new technology which does not work with IE versions below 10. Chrome, Firefox and Safari do support it.

The group of technologies that allow you to use javascript to communicate with the server instead of requiring browser page refreshes is called AJAX.

A library like DWR makes it very easy to do AJAX between Javascript and Java. It also has a feature called Reverse AJAX that allows you to write Java code that executes javascript code on the client. http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/index.html

With DWR you can write this to show a popup on all connected clients:

```
    Container container = ServerContextFactory.get().getContainer();
    ScriptSessionManager manager = container.getBean(ScriptSessionManager.class);
    System.out.println("sessions: " + manager.getAllScriptSessions().size());
    for (ScriptSession scriptSession : manager.getAllScriptSessions()) {
        System.out.println("Sending script to session " + scriptSession);
        ScriptBuffer script = new ScriptBuffer("window.alert('hello from reverse ajax server');");
        scriptSession.addScript(script);
    }
```

Comment: Trying this out! Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't show up the alert, but the sessions exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you need the popup to appear immediately and you can't wait for a page-request, you need some kind of communication channel from server to client which allows pushing messages.

A good tool for this are Javascript [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/WebSockets). A WebSocket is a bidirectional connection between browser and server which is open while the page is open and which can be used by both sides to send data whenever they want.

On every page you need to create a websocket and connect it to a [WebSocket Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm). While the client has the page open, that servlet is able to send a message to the client whenever it wants. You can then handle that message in Javascript to implement a real-time chat application.

Comment: is it possibly to send data to only one browser (with specific session userid) and not to all browsers while they are all connected?

Comment: @y451n Yes. The servlet just needs to track the userId's of all sessions.